# Switch branch preserving files

Tags: git, svn

### Background

I've been running both subversion and git on a single codebase. This works well: I can commit to the existing remote subversion repository, and use git as a local backup for storing temporary commits. So I can commit to git as soon as something is working, but continue tidying it up before committing it to subversion for sharing with others.

I'm know I could be using git-svn for this, but I'm happy with the solution I have. Unless something goes wrong and I need to backtrack, git is effectively write-only.

### What I'm trying to do

If I switch branches in subversion, I can commit everything to git's `master` branch and then start tracking again from there. But I feel it would be better to have branches in git that mirror those in subversion so there are fewer files to stage in git each time.

**How can I switch branches in git without checking out from the branch?** I want the files to change based on the svn switch, but not be overwritten from git. I just want the changes be available for staging in git as if I had made them manually, and have this work each time I switch between branches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git symbolic-ref` for this purpose.  Where `$BRANCH` is the local Git branch you are trying to switch to:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/$BRANCH
```

You may want to follow this command with `git reset` to update the index to match the state of the branch that `HEAD` now targets.  (This will of course discard any index manipulations you have done, but will not affect the files in your working copy.)