switch to different branch keeping files of current branch
Suppose I have 2 branches develop and feature.
I start on feature branch. What I want is checkout to develop branch but keep the files exactly like they are on feature branch, so that if I write git status, I see all the differences created by feature. Is there a quick way to do this?

A possible solution is to duplicate the project, have an instance on branch develop and other on branch feature, then copy feature and paste on develop, but this is slow and I'd prefer to avoid.

I don't think this might be possible. However, you should update your question and clarify that you're not talking about local uncommitted changes, but fully committed changes.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196331/switch-branch-preserving-files Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+switch+branch+preserve+files

I saw this command git checkout feature -- . (executed while being on develop) and tested. Looks like it worked.

@Daniel git checkout feature -- . copies files from the tip of feature but doesn't remove files that are not in feature. git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/develop works much faster (doesn't touch files, only manipulates references) and more correct (completely preserve the current working tree).

To switch to a different Git branch while keeping the files from your current branch unchanged, you can "stash" your changes and apply them later, or use the git checkout command with specific options.
Here’s how you can do it:
Switching Branches Without Committing Changes (Using Stash)
If you have uncommitted changes and want to switch to another branch but keep your changes, you can use the stash command to temporarily save those changes:
Step-by-step:
Stash your current changes:
git stash
This command saves your uncommitted changes temporarily and restores your working directory to match the last commit on the current branch.
Switch to the new branch:
git checkout 
Apply the stashed changes: After switching branches, you can bring back your changes:
git stash apply
This restores your stashed changes to the new branch.
Hope this help!!

I have no "current changes", it is only a branch with a lot of commits.
